# UML Custom Image Extension

Tags: uml

Any idea or link of how to declare / use a particular image or icon to represent a custom or commonly used class / object in U.M.L. (Custom U.M.L. extension), not just "<< my stereotype >>" ?

By example, U.M.L. 2.* has custom images for 3 - layers methodology:

[image: Custom image for layers]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there's no formal and/or standard way to define custom representations in the language itself.  There are tools which support it (e.g. MagicDraw, Rational Rose iirc) but the mechanism is tool-dependent.

hth.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an image to your stereotype. 
It means you will have image+stereotype then below the name of the class.

A demo from Omondo on this subject available at: http://www.download-omondo.com/dsl_modeling_with_uml.swf

*This is not streaming therefore you have to wait to download the full flash.*